# print a string without quotation marks in a flat file in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, quotation-marks

Im creating a vba Function which creates a flat file with just one line, on same directory of my Excel file, everything works fine

but when I print that line which is contained inside of a string I get my message inside of quotation marks

if I expect something like

> HDR201412101136452014121090105500000000000000000000

I get this

> "HDR201412101136452014121090105500000000000000000000"

this is my code:

```
Public Function generateFlatFile()

    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FLAT_FILE_NAME For Output As #1

    Dim header As String
    header = "HDR"
    header = header & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhnnss")
    header = header & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")
    header = header & Worksheets(BD).Cells(2, 3)
    header = header & 5
    header = header & "00000000000000000000"

    Write #1, header

    Close #1
End Function
```

Comment: Try `Print #1, generaHeader`

Comment: Do you mean `header` instead of `generaHeader`?

Comment: my bad, I developed a Function for generating and returning Header string because final code will be more complex, but for this question I can put everything inside of generateFlatFile Function, code updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Write #n` will enclose strings in quotation marks. If you want full control over how the file gets written, you need to use `Print #n` instead.